# Working out a difficult case with NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, swift, nsregularexpression

I am using the Swift Playground to experiment with `NSRegularExpression` and I do not get what I would like to.
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

let str = "qwun782h218gs634  AbCd56EfGh7ZsDe985\nXzSr519UkGe9823SdFg91nui uihiheg875d dss77ds",
patn = "(([A-Z][a-z]){2}([0-9]+)){3}",
rgx  = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: patn, options: .AnchorsMatchLines)

print("Start with:\(str)")
let strNS = str as NSString

rgx.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options: .ReportCompletion,
                                          range: NSMakeRange(0,str.utf8.count),
                                          usingBlock: { (result, _, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
                                            if let _ = result?.range.location {
                                                var n = 0,
                                                theStr = strNS.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange((result?.rangeAtIndex(n).location)!,
                                                    (result?.rangeAtIndex(n).length)!))
                                                print("xpr [\(n)]: \(theStr)")
                                                n = 1
                                                theStr = strNS.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange((result?.rangeAtIndex(n).location)!,
                                                    (result?.rangeAtIndex(n).length)!))
                                                print("xpr [\(n)]: \(theStr)")
                                                n = 2
                                                theStr = strNS.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange((result?.rangeAtIndex(n).location)!,
                                                    (result?.rangeAtIndex(n).length)!))
                                                print("xpr [\(n)]: \(theStr)")
                                                n = 3
                                                theStr = strNS.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange((result?.rangeAtIndex(n).location)!,
                                                    (result?.rangeAtIndex(n).length)!))
                                                print("xpr [\(n)]: \(theStr)")
                                           }
})
```

This is what I get in the result console:

```
Start with:qwun782h218gs634  AbCd56EfGh7ZsDe985
XzSr519UkGe9823SdFg91nui uihiheg875d dss77ds

xpr [0]: AbCd56EfGh7ZsDe985
xpr [1]: ZsDe985
xpr [2]: De
xpr [3]: 985
xpr [0]: XzSr519UkGe9823SdFg91
xpr [1]: SdFg91
xpr [2]: Fg
xpr [3]: 91
```

Finally here is what I am interested in:

```
xpr: 56
xpr: 7
xpr: 985
xpr: 519
xpr: 9823
xpr: 91
```

In other words I want to capture all the groups of numbers.

In this example, I could of course change the shape of my regular expression, get rid of the **{2}** and **{3}** and make it work (by extending it).
But this is not what I want and this is the purpose of my question. How can I keep this compacted form of the regular expression, while being able to capture what I want?

If instead of **{2}** and **{3}**, I had **{12}** and **{37}**; nobody would like to extend the expression :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the regex `\\d+` (one numeric character or more) is sufficient.

```
let patn = "\\d+"
let str = "AbCd56EfGh7ZsDe985\nXzSr519UkGe9823SdFg91",
rgx  = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: patn, options: [])

print("Start with:\(str)")

rgx.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSRange(location:0, length:str.characters.count)) { (result, _, _) in
  if result != nil { print("xpr: \((str as NSString).substringWithRange(result!.range))") }
}
```

Comment: You are right about the "numeric character or more", but that does not answer my question. I am not looking for sequence of numeric characters in general. I am looking for sequence of numbers inside a pattern described by this regular expression:
`"(([A-Z][a-z]){2}([0-9]+)){3}"` which is a very different issue.

Comment: You wrote *Finally here is what I am interested in* and the simple regex does that exactly ;-)

Comment: After rereading my post, I realized that your interpretation of my question was after all correct. I therefore edited the post to make the question clearer and unambiguous. Sorry for that misleading.